# Is an internship verification letter required for hiring?

Tags: hiring-process, internship, relieving-letter

I landed an unpaid internship a while back on a small news company but I quit after one month. I didn't include it on my resume because I didn't receive a verification letter, most likely because I quit all of a sudden.

I don't have a lot of work experience and I think including it on my resume would look better. I have gained a number of skills during that time, but I'm worried that any future employer would ask for a verification letter which I don't have, and won't ask for it.

Is it important for an employer to verify this?
and is there another way to note this experience without having to provide this verification letter?

Answer (score 3):

If you quit after one month, your best option is to leave this off the resume entirely. That isn't a significant amount of experience, and it raises more concerns than it answers.

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned that you quit after one month and you don't have a verification letter so my recommendation is not to include that in your resume. But you have gained a lot of knowledge and skills in one month so you can use that to impress your recruiter. In this way he won't be interested in you internship or letter, he will be   interested in your skills.